# glRotatef, координаты OpenGl

Tags: delphi, координаты, opengl

Доброго вечера! Я никогда игр не писал, за исключением, текстовых, например: виселица и поэтому возможно все ниже описанное делается запросто, но я этого не могу сделать). Ну теперь по порядку. Вначале этой недели начал изучать opengl на delphi по книге "Open GL Графика в проектах Delphi. Михаил Краснов". Прочитал все до 3д, т.к хочу научиться работать более-менее нормально в 2д, а потом лезть уже в дебри 3д. Так вот для первой своей реализации взял не всякие MMORPG, как тут некоторые выбирают, а подобие танчиков на денди.
Собственно сам танк я нарисовал и сделал его вращение, но вот незадача команда glrotatef удлиняет объект, если форма не квадратная(800x600). Единственным моим решением стало - использование квадратного разрешения для игры (800x800). Если есть другой способ поворачивания объекта без его удлинения/укорачивания, то просьба написать об этом.

Вторая моя проблема - координаты самих танков и стенок. Как лучше всего осуществить координаты? Была идея проверки линии пикселей на определенные цвета, но, т.к прямое обращение к пикселям медленно, то сразу отпадает этот метод.

P.S всем спасибо, кто не поленился прочитать пост!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По первой проблеме тебе скорее всего нужна ортографическая проекция.